# Topology: Show, that if $A\cap\mathcal{O}=\emptyset$ then $\overline{A}\cap\mathcal{O}=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Within a proof I need the following step.

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}$) be a topological space and $A\subset X$. If $\mathcal{O}\in\mathcal{T}$ such that $A\cap\mathcal{O}=\emptyset$, then also $\overline{A}\cap\mathcal{O}=\emptyset$.

Comment: HINT: What does $x\in \overline{A}$ means?

Comment: $x\in\overline{A}$ means that $\forall$ neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$, we have that $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$ right?.

Comment: and... What is a neigborhood of $x$? Try to use Reductio ad Absurdum.

Comment: Ahhh stupid me, I was thinking much too complicated....Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \cap \mathcal{O} = \emptyset \overset{(1)}{\iff} A \subset \mathcal{O}^{c} \overset{(2)}{\iff} \overline{A} \subset \mathcal{O}^{c} \overset{(1)}{\iff} \overline{A} \cap \mathcal{O} = \emptyset$

$(1)$ Property of sets.

$(2)$ Because $\mathcal{O}^{c}$ is closed, and because by definition  closure is intersection of all closed supersets.